# Blazor invoke JS from synchronous method

Tags: c#, async-await, blazor-server-side

I have a piece of code in an `Action` that is querying a JS funtion.

Unfortunately I didn't make my registered action `async` at first and realized that the following code was stuck at the `InvokeAsync` line

```
async Task someCode() {
    string myRes = await jsRuntime.InvokeAsync<string>("MyMethod");
    Console.WriteLine(myCode); // <- this line was not reached!
}

public void myAction() {
    // synchronous here => how to convert it to synchronous code?!
    someCode.GetAwaiter().Result();
}
```

Because of this, the `WriteLine` part of code was not reached... Is there a proper way to call the `async` method here from the synchrounous method? Can anyone clarify why the following code works :

```
public async Task myAction() {
    await someCode;
}
```

Comment: Do you have an update?

Comment: cast `jsRuntime` to [`(IJSInProcessRuntime)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.jsinterop.ijsinprocessruntime?view=aspnetcore-7.0) which has sychronous Invoke() method

Answer (score 1):

I'm using the following:

```cs
string myRes = ((IJSInProcessRuntime)jsRuntime).Invoke<string>("MyMethood");
```

It's not recommended tho, `async` version gets you better performance.

Comment: Just tried this on a Blazor Server app. I got this error:

System.InvalidCastException
  HResult=0x80004002
  Message=Unable to cast object of type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Server.Circuits.RemoteJSRuntime' to type 'Microsoft.JSInterop.IJSInProcessRuntime'.

Comment: @MarioMucalo Because the rendering is happening server-side, js cannot be run synchonously. It is only possible on wasm apps.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you have a sort of deadlock, change `myAction`:

```
public void myAction() {

 var result = someCode.ConfigureAwait(false)
            .GetAwaiter()
            .GetResult();
}
```

Comment: nope deadlock still occurs this way!

Answer (score -1):

Could be because `InvokeAsync` returns a `ValueTask` type. You cannot get the result of a `ValueTask`. You have to convert it to a Task to read the result synchronously.

Check the remarks of the [`ValueTask` docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.valuetask-1?view=net-6.0#remarks). Specifically the bullet points:

> The following operations should never be performed on a `ValueTask<TResult>` instance
>
> - Awaiting the instance multiple times.
> - Calling `AsTask` multiple times.
> - **Using `.Result` or `.GetAwaiter().GetResult()` when the operation hasn't yet completed, or using them multiple times.**
> - Using more than one of these techniques to consume the instance.

I know you are calling `.GetResult()` on a `Task` returned by `someCode()`, but I'm guessing it's not behaving the way you want because you're indirectly trying to get the result of a `ValueTask`. Two possible options would be:

1. Use `Invoke` instead of `InvokeAsync`. This is only available for Blazor WASM apps. See [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/javascript-interoperability/call-javascript-from-dotnet?view=aspnetcore-6.0#synchronous-js-interop-in-blazor-webassembly-apps).
2. Cast the `ValueTask` to a `Task` to get result properly. For example, `string myRes = await jsRuntime.InvokeAsync<string>("MyMethod").AsTask();`.

Comment: In blazor/wasm, you cannot use GetAwaiter() (get Monitor) since the client-side code runs single-threaded.